# HTML5 Canvas Pathfinding for an object within a drawn polygon

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

Good afternoon all,

I come to you with yet another request for a lesson/example/answers. While messing around with a canvas in HTML5, I have learned how to manipulate Depth(Z-Buffer) and several other neat things. However, now I am trying to find a way to perform Pathfinding with the canvas. Most of the examples on the Internet are a little difficult to comprehend for me due to the fact that they are handling pathfinding far differently than I am trying to achieve(Which is that they use tile based pathfinding). Most other examples seem to deal in boxes or rectangles as well.

This is my code that I used as an example to draw a Polygon:
var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvasPath');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

```
  // begin custom shape
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(1, 200, 125, 230, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 200, 340, 200);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);


  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
  context.stroke();
```

Lets say I have a small box that I want to move around in that Polygon(I really will be creating the polygon with line points rather than Bezier curvers. I just wantd to show an example here) when I click at the goal position I want it to be at... How can I create a pathfinding algorithm that will find its way around and yet not have the bottom points of the box touch outside the polygon? I am assuming I would need to get all the pixels that are in that polygon to create a path from? I am thinking that the Bezier Curves and points may need to be created and pushed from an Array instead and then find the path???

Any suggestions on approach and can you provide an example for how to  go about this? Please be gentle... While I have been an experienced scripter and programmer, I have not been one to mess to much with games, or graphics and I am still  learning to manipulate the canvas in HTML5. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of what you are asking is how to shrink a polygon so that your box can travel along the shrunken polygon without extending outside the original polygon.

The illustration below shows an original black polygon, a shrunken red polygon and a blue traveling box.

[image]

**Precisely shrinking a polygon**

The code to precisely shrink a polygon is quite complex. It involves repositioning the original polygon vertices based on whether each particular vertex forms a convex or concave angle.

Here's example code I derived from [Hans Muller's Blog on Webkits Shape-Padding](http://hansmuller-webkit.blogspot.com/2013/04/growing-and-shrinking-polygons-round-one.html). This example requires that the polygon vertices defined in a clockwise order.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var shapePadding = 10;
var dragVertexIndex = null;
var hoverLocation = null;
var polygonVertexRadius = 9;
var polygon, marginPolygon, paddingPolygon;

var polygonVertices =  [{x: 143, y: 327}, {x: 80, y: 236}, {x: 151, y: 148}, {x: 454, y: 69}, {x: 560, y: 320}];
var polygon = createPolygon(polygonVertices);
var paddingPolygon = createPaddingPolygon(polygon);

drawAll();


/////////////////////////////////
// Polygon creation and drawing

function drawAll(){
  draw(polygon,'black');
  draw(paddingPolygon,'red');
}

function draw(p,stroke){
  var v=p.vertices;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(v[0].x,v[0].y);
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(v[i].x,v[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=stroke;
  ctx.stroke();
}

function createPolygon(vertices){
  var polygon = {vertices: vertices};
  var edges = [];
  var minX = (vertices.length > 0) ? vertices[0].x : undefined;
  var minY = (vertices.length > 0) ? vertices[0].y : undefined;
  var maxX = minX;
  var maxY = minY;

  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.vertices.length; i++) {
    vertices[i].label = String(i);
    vertices[i].isReflex = isReflexVertex(polygon, i);
    var edge = {
      vertex1: vertices[i], 
      vertex2: vertices[(i + 1) % vertices.length], 
      polygon: polygon, 
      index: i
    };
    edge.outwardNormal = outwardEdgeNormal(edge);
    edge.inwardNormal = inwardEdgeNormal(edge);
    edges.push(edge);
    var x = vertices[i].x;
    var y = vertices[i].y;
    minX = Math.min(x, minX);
    minY = Math.min(y, minY);
    maxX = Math.max(x, maxX);
    maxY = Math.max(y, maxY);
  }                       

  polygon.edges = edges;
  polygon.minX = minX;
  polygon.minY = minY;
  polygon.maxX = maxX;
  polygon.maxY = maxY;
  polygon.closed = true;

  return polygon;
}

function createPaddingPolygon(polygon){
  var offsetEdges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.edges.length; i++) {
    var edge = polygon.edges[i];
    var dx = edge.inwardNormal.x * shapePadding;
    var dy = edge.inwardNormal.y * shapePadding;
    offsetEdges.push(createOffsetEdge(edge, dx, dy));
  }

  var vertices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < offsetEdges.length; i++) {
    var thisEdge = offsetEdges[i];
    var prevEdge = offsetEdges[(i + offsetEdges.length - 1) % offsetEdges.length];
    var vertex = edgesIntersection(prevEdge, thisEdge);
    if (vertex)
      vertices.push(vertex);
    else {
      var arcCenter = polygon.edges[i].vertex1;
      appendArc(vertices, arcCenter, shapePadding, prevEdge.vertex2, thisEdge.vertex1, true);
    }
  }

  var paddingPolygon = createPolygon(vertices);
  paddingPolygon.offsetEdges = offsetEdges;
  return paddingPolygon;
}


//////////////////////
// Support functions


function isReflexVertex(polygon, vertexIndex){
  // Assuming that polygon vertices are in clockwise order
  var thisVertex = polygon.vertices[vertexIndex];
  var nextVertex = polygon.vertices[(vertexIndex + 1) % polygon.vertices.length];
  var prevVertex = polygon.vertices[(vertexIndex + polygon.vertices.length - 1) % polygon.vertices.length];
  if (leftSide(prevVertex, nextVertex, thisVertex) < 0){return true;}  // TBD: return true if thisVertex is inside polygon when thisVertex isn't included
  return false;
}

function inwardEdgeNormal(edge){
  // Assuming that polygon vertices are in clockwise order
  var dx = edge.vertex2.x - edge.vertex1.x;
  var dy = edge.vertex2.y - edge.vertex1.y;
  var edgeLength = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  return {x: -dy/edgeLength, y: dx/edgeLength};
}

function outwardEdgeNormal(edge){
  var n = inwardEdgeNormal(edge);
  return {x: -n.x, y: -n.y};
}

// If the slope of line vertex1,vertex2 greater than the slope of vertex1,p then p is on the left side of vertex1,vertex2 and the return value is > 0.
// If p is colinear with vertex1,vertex2 then return 0, otherwise return a value < 0.
function leftSide(vertex1, vertex2, p){
  return ((p.x - vertex1.x) * (vertex2.y - vertex1.y)) - ((vertex2.x - vertex1.x) * (p.y - vertex1.y));
}

function createOffsetEdge(edge, dx, dy){
  return {
    vertex1: {x: edge.vertex1.x + dx, y: edge.vertex1.y + dy},
    vertex2: {x: edge.vertex2.x + dx, y: edge.vertex2.y + dy}
  };
}

// based on http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/, edgeA => "line a", edgeB => "line b"
function edgesIntersection(edgeA, edgeB){
  var den = (edgeB.vertex2.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) * (edgeA.vertex2.x - edgeA.vertex1.x) - (edgeB.vertex2.x - edgeB.vertex1.x) * (edgeA.vertex2.y - edgeA.vertex1.y);
  if (den == 0){return null;}  // lines are parallel or conincident

  var ua = ((edgeB.vertex2.x - edgeB.vertex1.x) * (edgeA.vertex1.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) - (edgeB.vertex2.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) * (edgeA.vertex1.x - edgeB.vertex1.x)) / den;
  var ub = ((edgeA.vertex2.x - edgeA.vertex1.x) * (edgeA.vertex1.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) - (edgeA.vertex2.y - edgeA.vertex1.y) * (edgeA.vertex1.x - edgeB.vertex1.x)) / den;

  if (ua < 0 || ub < 0 || ua > 1 || ub > 1){ return null; }

  return {x: edgeA.vertex1.x + ua * (edgeA.vertex2.x - edgeA.vertex1.x),  y: edgeA.vertex1.y + ua * (edgeA.vertex2.y - edgeA.vertex1.y)};
}

function appendArc(vertices, center, radius, startVertex, endVertex, isPaddingBoundary){
  const twoPI = Math.PI * 2;
  var startAngle = Math.atan2(startVertex.y - center.y, startVertex.x - center.x);
  var endAngle = Math.atan2(endVertex.y - center.y, endVertex.x - center.x);
  if (startAngle < 0)
    startAngle += twoPI;
  if (endAngle < 0)
    endAngle += twoPI;
  var arcSegmentCount = 5; // An odd number so that one arc vertex will be eactly arcRadius from center.
  var angle = ((startAngle > endAngle) ? (startAngle - endAngle) : (startAngle + twoPI - endAngle));
  var angle5 =  ((isPaddingBoundary) ? -angle : twoPI - angle) / arcSegmentCount;

  vertices.push(startVertex);
  for (var i = 1; i < arcSegmentCount; ++i) {
    var angle = startAngle + angle5 * i;
    var vertex = {
      x: center.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
      y: center.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius,
    };
    vertices.push(vertex);
  }
  vertices.push(endVertex);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Original black polygon and shrunken red polygon</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=650 height=400></canvas>
```

**Calculating the waypoints along the polygon for your traveling box**

To have your box travel along the inside of the polygon, you need an array containing points along each line of the polygon. You can calculate these points using `linear interpolation`.

Given an object defining a line like this:

```
var line={
    x0:50,
    y0:50,
    x1:200,
    y1:50};
```

You can use linear interpolation to calculate points along that line every 1px like this:

```
var allPoints = allLinePoints(line);

function allLinePoints(line){
    var raw=[];
    var dx = line.x1-line.x0;
    var dy = line.y1-line.y0;
    var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var segments=parseInt(length+1);
    for(var i=0;i<segments;i++){
        var percent=i/segments;
        if(i==segments-1){
            raw.push({x:line.x1,y:line.y1}); // force last point == p1
        }else{
            raw.push({ x:line.x0+dx*percent, y:line.y0+dy*percent});
        }
    }
    return(raw);
}
```

**Get the point on the polygon closest to the mouse click**

You can use the distance formula (derived from Pythagorean theorem) to calculate which of the calculated waypoints is closest to the mouse click position:

```
// this will be the index in of the waypoint closest to the mouse
var indexOfClosestPoint;

// iterate all waypoints and find the closest to the mouse

var minLengthSquared=1000000*1000000;

for(var i=0;i<allPoints.length;i++){
    var p=allPoints[i];
    var dx=mouseX-p.x;
    var dy=mouseY-p.y;
    var dxy=dx*dx+dy*dy
    if(dxy<minLengthSquared){
        minLengthSquared=dxy;
        indexOfClosestPoint=i;
    }
}
```

**Animate the box along each waypoint up to the calculated ending waypoint**

The only thing left to do is set up an animation loop that redraws the traveling box at each waypoint along the polygon until it reaches the ending waypoint:

```
// start animating at the first waypoint
var animationIndex=0;

// use requestAnimationFrame to redraw the traveling box
// along each waypoint

function animate(time){

    // redraw the line and the box at its current (percent) position
    var pt=allPoints[animationIndex];

    // redraw the polygon and the traveling box
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';         
    drawLines(linePoints);
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    drawLines(insideLinePoints);
    ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
    ctx.fillRect(pt.x-boxWidth/2,pt.y-boxHeight/2,boxWidth,boxHeight);

    // increase the percentage for the next frame loop
    animationIndex++;

    // Are we done?
    if(animationIndex<=indexOfClosestPoint){
        // request another frame loop
        requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    }else{
        // set the flag indicating the animation is complete
        isAnimating=false;
    }

}
```

**Here's what it looks like when you put it all together**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;
        function reOffset(){
            var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            offsetX=BB.left;
            offsetY=BB.top;        
        }
        var offsetX,offsetY;
        reOffset();
        window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }


// polygon vertices
var polygonVertices=[
    {x:143,y:327},
    {x:80,y:236},
    {x:151,y:148},
    {x:454,y:69},
    {x:560,y:320},
];
var shrunkenVertices=getShrunkenVertices(polygonVertices,10);
var polyPoints=getPolygonPoints(shrunkenVertices)

//log(shrunkenVertices);

// animation variables
var isAnimating=false;
var animationIndex=0;

//
var indexOfClosestPoint=-99;

// define the movable box
var boxWidth=12;
var boxHeight=10;
var boxRadius=Math.sqrt(boxWidth*boxWidth+boxHeight*boxHeight);
var boxFill='skyblue';

// listen for mouse events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


drawPolys(polygonVertices,shrunkenVertices);



////////////////////////////
// animate box to endpoint
////////////////////////////

function animate(time){

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

    drawPolys(polygonVertices,shrunkenVertices);

    // redraw the line and the box at its current (percent) position
    var pt=polyPoints[animationIndex];
    ctx.fillStyle=boxFill;
    ctx.fillRect(pt.x-boxWidth/2,pt.y-boxHeight/2,boxWidth,boxHeight);
    
    // increase the percentage for the next frame loop
    animationIndex++;

    // request another frame loop
    if(animationIndex<=indexOfClosestPoint){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    }else{
        isAnimating=false;
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////
// select box endpoint with click
////////////////////////////////////

function handleMouseDown(e){
    // return if we're already animating
    if(isAnimating){return;}     
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // start animating
    animationIndex=0;
    isAnimating=true;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);      
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
    // return if we're already animating
    if(isAnimating){return;}
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // get mouse position
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // find the nearest waypoint
    indexOfClosestPoint=findNearestPointToMouse(mouseX,mouseY);
    // redraw
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);    
    drawPolys(polygonVertices,shrunkenVertices);
    // draw a red dot at the nearest waypoint
    drawDot(polyPoints[indexOfClosestPoint],'red');
}

function findNearestPointToMouse(mx,my){
    // find the nearest waypoint
    var minLengthSquared=1000000*1000000;
    for(var i=0;i<polyPoints.length;i++){
        var p=polyPoints[i];
        var dx=mouseX-p.x;
        var dy=mouseY-p.y;
        var dxy=dx*dx+dy*dy
        if(dxy<minLengthSquared){
            minLengthSquared=dxy;
            indexOfClosestPoint=i;
        }
    }
    return(indexOfClosestPoint);
}


////////////////////////////////
// Drawing functions
////////////////////////////////

function drawPolys(polygon,shrunken){
    drawPoly(polygon,'black');
    drawPoly(shrunken,'blue');
}

function drawPoly(v,stroke){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(v[0].x,v[0].y);
    for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(v[i].x,v[i].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle=stroke;
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawDot(pt,color){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pt.x,pt.y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    ctx.fill();
}


////////////////////////////////
// Get points along a polygon
////////////////////////////////

function getPolygonPoints(vertices){
    // For this purpose, be sure to close the polygon
    var v=vertices.slice(0);
    var v0=v[0];
    var vx=v[v.length-1];
    if(v0.x!==vx.x || v0.y!==vx.y){v.push(v[0]);}
    //
    var points=[];
    for(var i=1;i<v.length;i++){
        var p0=v[i-1];
        var p1=v[i];
        var line={x0:p0.x,y0:p0.y,x1:p1.x,y1:p1.y};
        points=points.concat(getLinePoints(line));
    }
    return(points);
}

function getLinePoints(line){
    var raw=[];
    var dx = line.x1-line.x0;
    var dy = line.y1-line.y0;
    var length=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var segments=parseInt(length+1);
    for(var i=0;i<segments;i++){
        var percent=i/segments;
        if(i==segments-1){
            raw.push({x:line.x1,y:line.y1}); // force last point == p1
        }else{
            raw.push({ x:line.x0+dx*percent, y:line.y0+dy*percent});
        }
    }
    return(raw);
}


/////////////////////////
// "shrink" a polygon
/////////////////////////

function getShrunkenVertices(vertices,shapePadding){
    var polygon = createPolygon(polygonVertices);
    var paddingPolygon = createPaddingPolygon(polygon,shapePadding);
    return(paddingPolygon.vertices);
}

function createPolygon(vertices){
    var polygon = {vertices: vertices};
    var edges = [];
    var minX = (vertices.length > 0) ? vertices[0].x : undefined;
    var minY = (vertices.length > 0) ? vertices[0].y : undefined;
    var maxX = minX;
    var maxY = minY;

    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.vertices.length; i++) {
        vertices[i].label = String(i);
        vertices[i].isReflex = isReflexVertex(polygon, i);
        var edge = {
            vertex1: vertices[i], 
            vertex2: vertices[(i + 1) % vertices.length], 
            polygon: polygon, 
            index: i
        };
        edge.outwardNormal = outwardEdgeNormal(edge);
        edge.inwardNormal = inwardEdgeNormal(edge);
        edges.push(edge);
        var x = vertices[i].x;
        var y = vertices[i].y;
        minX = Math.min(x, minX);
        minY = Math.min(y, minY);
        maxX = Math.max(x, maxX);
        maxY = Math.max(y, maxY);
    }                       
    
    polygon.edges = edges;
    polygon.minX = minX;
    polygon.minY = minY;
    polygon.maxX = maxX;
    polygon.maxY = maxY;
    polygon.closed = true;

    return polygon;
}

function createPaddingPolygon(polygon,shapePadding){
    var offsetEdges = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.edges.length; i++) {
        var edge = polygon.edges[i];
        var dx = edge.inwardNormal.x * shapePadding;
        var dy = edge.inwardNormal.y * shapePadding;
        offsetEdges.push(createOffsetEdge(edge, dx, dy));
    }

    var vertices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < offsetEdges.length; i++) {
        var thisEdge = offsetEdges[i];
        var prevEdge = offsetEdges[(i + offsetEdges.length - 1) % offsetEdges.length];
        var vertex = edgesIntersection(prevEdge, thisEdge);
        if (vertex)
            vertices.push(vertex);
        else {
            var arcCenter = polygon.edges[i].vertex1;
            appendArc(vertices, arcCenter, shapePadding, prevEdge.vertex2, thisEdge.vertex1, true);
        }
    }

    var paddingPolygon = createPolygon(vertices);
    paddingPolygon.offsetEdges = offsetEdges;
    return paddingPolygon;
}

function isReflexVertex(polygon, vertexIndex){
    // Assuming that polygon vertices are in clockwise order
    var thisVertex = polygon.vertices[vertexIndex];
    var nextVertex = polygon.vertices[(vertexIndex + 1) % polygon.vertices.length];
    var prevVertex = polygon.vertices[(vertexIndex + polygon.vertices.length - 1) % polygon.vertices.length];
    if (leftSide(prevVertex, nextVertex, thisVertex) < 0){return true;}  // TBD: return true if thisVertex is inside polygon when thisVertex isn't included
    return false;
}

function inwardEdgeNormal(edge){
    // Assuming that polygon vertices are in clockwise order
    var dx = edge.vertex2.x - edge.vertex1.x;
    var dy = edge.vertex2.y - edge.vertex1.y;
    var edgeLength = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    return {x: -dy/edgeLength, y: dx/edgeLength};
}

function outwardEdgeNormal(edge){
    var n = inwardEdgeNormal(edge);
    return {x: -n.x, y: -n.y};
}

// If the slope of line vertex1,vertex2 greater than the slope of vertex1,p then p is on the left side of vertex1,vertex2 and the return value is > 0.
// If p is colinear with vertex1,vertex2 then return 0, otherwise return a value < 0.
function leftSide(vertex1, vertex2, p){
    return ((p.x - vertex1.x) * (vertex2.y - vertex1.y)) - ((vertex2.x - vertex1.x) * (p.y - vertex1.y));
}

function createOffsetEdge(edge, dx, dy){
    return {
        vertex1: {x: edge.vertex1.x + dx, y: edge.vertex1.y + dy},
        vertex2: {x: edge.vertex2.x + dx, y: edge.vertex2.y + dy}
    };
}

// based on http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/, edgeA => "line a", edgeB => "line b"
function edgesIntersection(edgeA, edgeB){
    var den = (edgeB.vertex2.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) * (edgeA.vertex2.x - edgeA.vertex1.x) - (edgeB.vertex2.x - edgeB.vertex1.x) * (edgeA.vertex2.y - edgeA.vertex1.y);
    if (den == 0){return null;}  // lines are parallel or conincident

    var ua = ((edgeB.vertex2.x - edgeB.vertex1.x) * (edgeA.vertex1.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) - (edgeB.vertex2.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) * (edgeA.vertex1.x - edgeB.vertex1.x)) / den;
    var ub = ((edgeA.vertex2.x - edgeA.vertex1.x) * (edgeA.vertex1.y - edgeB.vertex1.y) - (edgeA.vertex2.y - edgeA.vertex1.y) * (edgeA.vertex1.x - edgeB.vertex1.x)) / den;

    if (ua < 0 || ub < 0 || ua > 1 || ub > 1){ return null; }

    return {x: edgeA.vertex1.x + ua * (edgeA.vertex2.x - edgeA.vertex1.x),  y: edgeA.vertex1.y + ua * (edgeA.vertex2.y - edgeA.vertex1.y)};
}

function appendArc(vertices, center, radius, startVertex, endVertex, isPaddingBoundary){
    const twoPI = Math.PI * 2;
    var startAngle = Math.atan2(startVertex.y - center.y, startVertex.x - center.x);
    var endAngle = Math.atan2(endVertex.y - center.y, endVertex.x - center.x);
    if (startAngle < 0)
        startAngle += twoPI;
    if (endAngle < 0)
        endAngle += twoPI;
    var arcSegmentCount = 5; // An odd number so that one arc vertex will be eactly arcRadius from center.
    var angle = ((startAngle > endAngle) ? (startAngle - endAngle) : (startAngle + twoPI - endAngle));
    var angle5 =  ((isPaddingBoundary) ? -angle : twoPI - angle) / arcSegmentCount;

    vertices.push(startVertex);
    for (var i = 1; i < arcSegmentCount; ++i) {
        var angle = startAngle + angle5 * i;
        var vertex = {
            x: center.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
            y: center.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius,
        };
        vertices.push(vertex);
    }
    vertices.push(endVertex);
}

/////////////////////////
// End "shrink polygon"
/////////////////////////
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse to where you want the box to end up<br>Then click to start the box animating from start to end.<br>Note: The starting point is on the bottom left of the polygon</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=650 height=400></canvas>
```

**Using curved paths**

If you want to make your closed path with Bezier curves, you will have to calculate waypoints along the curves using De Casteljau's algorithm. You will want to over-sample the number of points--maybe 500 values of T between 0.00 and 1.00. Here is a javascript version of the algorithm that calculates x,y points at interval T along a Cubic Bezier Curve:

```
// De Casteljau's algorithm which calculates points along a cubic Bezier curve
// plot a point at interval T along a bezier curve
// T==0.00 at beginning of curve. T==1.00 at ending of curve
// Calculating 300 T's between 0-1 will usually define the curve sufficiently

function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am coming back to this after so long. What I was trying to do is something different though. Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ztzz6an/1/ . What I wanted to do was: Have a red dot in the black area. Wherever I click on the black area, I want the read dot to move towards that area without going outside the lines.